# nullpointer exception java android

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I need make a `perfomclick()` to execute the code below. There is a button called `mButtonLogin`, I need make `perfomclick()` when activity starts.

I have tried and read many Stackoverflow examples, but I can't make it work. log cat output it's a `Nullpointer` exception where I place the `perfomclick()`.

```
Button mButtonLogin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_story_post);
    mButtonLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_login);

    myclick();          
}

public void loginExample()
{
    // Login listener
    final OnLoginListener mOnLoginListener = new OnLoginListener()
    {
        //stuff
    };

    final OnPublishListener onPublishListener = new SimpleFacebook.OnPublishListener()
    {
        //stuff
    };

    //More stuff Final too Called feed

    mButtonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            mSimpleFacebook.login(mOnLoginListener);
            mSimpleFacebook.publish(feed, onPublishListener);
        }
    });
}
```

Why am I receiving a `Nullpointer` exception?

Comment: myclick(); <--- where is this defined?

Comment: post clear codes to make us understand, if you really need help.

Comment: If I post much code, I post much code, If I Post less code I post poor code......... Go to shit guys......... Who voted bad my post

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//put this in the OnCreate
mButtonLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_login);
mButtonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mSimpleFacebook.login(mOnLoginListener);
                mSimpleFacebook.publish(feed, onPublishListener);
            }
        });

// all your stuffs

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mButtonLogin.performClick();

    }
```

Comment: I tried, but in my oncreate not it don't resolve  mOnLoginListener, feed, and onPublishListener.              mSimpleFacebook.login(mOnLoginListener);
mSimpleFacebook.publish(feed, onPublishListener);